# Set-text in text-input only from flat-list

Tags: react-native

How to set text in text-input only if user select any item from flat-list. i have a text-input filed labeled as city that show a list of available city(filter with text) while typing city name.
Issue is i want only the city available from list but there is a bug that if user proceed without selecting any item the input text is remains as city name.

```
<View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.labelText} children={"City"} />
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.textInput}
                  ref={"city"}
                  onChangeText={city =>
                    this.setState(
                      { showCities: city != "" && city != null },
                      () => {
                        this.searchCityFunction(city);
                      }
                    )
                  }
                  // onChangeText={val => this.setState({city: val})}
                  onSubmitEditing={() => this.refs.pincode.focus()}
                  defaultValue={this.state.city}
                  keyboardType="email-address"
                  returnKeyType="next"
                  placeholder="City"
                  placeholderTextColor={Colors.placeHolderColor}
                  selectionColor={Colors.notificationHeaderTextColor}
                  maxLength={25}
                />
                {this.state.showCities && (
                  <FlatList
                    numColumns={1}
                    keyboardShouldPersistTaps={"always"}
                    keyboardDismissMode={"on-drag"}
                    maxHeight={Dimens.twoHundred}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this._ItemSeparatorComponent}
                    data={cityArr}
                    nestedScrollEnabled={true}
                    extraData={cityArr}
                    disableVirtualization={false}
                    style={styles.listContainer}
                    renderItem={this._renderItems}
                    ListEmptyComponent={() => {
                      return (
                        <Text
                          style={{
                            flex: 1,
                            marginTop: "50%",
                            textAlign: "center",
                            fontFamily: Fonts.SourceSansProSemibolds,
                            fontSize: Dimens.twenty,
                            padding: Dimens.tweleve
                          }}
                          children={"No city available by this name"}
                        />
                      );
                    }}
                    getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
                      length: 30,
                      offset: 30 * index,
                      index
                    })}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
                      (
                        index + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3))
                      ).toString();
                    }}
                  />
                )}
              </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "value" prop of TextInput, It is used to show the default value of the textinput field.
As the user will click the flatlist item, then city will be set and your textinput will start showing selected city name.

like:

```
<TextInput 
    value={this.state.city} 
    onChangeText = { (text) => { this.setState({ city: text}) } }
/>

renderItems= ({item}) =>{
//renterItem of Your Flatlist
return(
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({city : item.cityName})}>
  <Text>{item.cityName}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
)
}
```

Comment: this is not a issue actually i want to clear text or set 1st item item of list if user doest not select any item and got to another field

Comment: you want to intialize your city value on the app opening?
if yes, then set your city in componentDidMount, with the first index of your flatlist data.

this.setState({city : flatlistData[0]});